# How to re-create an equivalent to linux bash statement in Deno with Deno.Run

Tags: deno

How to re-create an equivalent to following Linux bash statement in Deno?

`docker compose exec container_name -uroot -ppass db_name < ./dbDump.sql`

I have tried the following:

```js
    const encoder = new TextEncoder
    const p = await Deno.run({
        cmd: [
            'docker',
            'compose',
            'exec',
            'container_name',
            'mysql',
            '-uroot',
            '-ppass',
            'db_name',
        ],
        stdout: 'piped',
        stderr: 'piped',
        stdin: "piped",
    })
    
    await p.stdin.write(encoder.encode(await Deno.readTextFile('./dbDump.sql')))
    await p.stdin.close()
    await p.close()
```

But for some reason whenever I do it this way I get an error `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 145: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version` which does not happen when I perform the exact same command in the bash.

Could someone please explain me how it has to be done properly?

Comment: Start by replacing this round-trip encoding: `encoder.encode(await Deno.readTextFile('./dbDump.sql'))` with `await Deno.readFile('./dbDump.sql')`. (No need to decode and re-encode since [`Deno.readFile`](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/~/Deno.readFile) will give you the `Promise<Uint8Array>` directly). Afterward, still getting the same error?

Comment: Same thing if I do it directly

Comment: I have tried to do the same procedure manually by dumping the sql file first, then using `docker compose exec container_name -uroot -ppass db_name < ./dbDump.sql` to imported and confirmed that everything works, but whenever I do the same procedure using Deno I am getting SQL syntax error which points to a string with an import statement where value is a string/php serialized data, it might be the encoding issue but information about Deno.run is very scarce especially in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a sample input file, it's impossible to be certain of your exact issue.

Given the context though, I suspect that your input file is too large for a single `proc.stdin.write()` call. Try using [the `writeAll()` function](https://doc.deno.land/https://deno.land/std@0.119.0/streams/conversion.ts/%7E/writeAll) to make sure the full payload goes through:

```typescript
import { writeAll } from "https://deno.land/std@0.119.0/streams/conversion.ts";
await writeAll(proc.stdin, await Deno.readFile(sqlFilePath));
```

To show what this fixes, here's a Deno program `pipe-to-wc.ts` which passes its input to the Linux 'word count' utility (in character-counting mode):

```js
#!/usr/bin/env -S deno run --allow-read=/dev/stdin --allow-run=wc
const proc = await Deno.run({
  cmd: ['wc', '-c'],
  stdin: 'piped',
});

await proc.stdin.write(await Deno.readFile('/dev/stdin'));
proc.stdin.close();
await proc.status();
```

If we use this program with a small input, the count lines up:

```
# use the shebang to make the following commands easier
$ chmod +x pipe-to-wc.ts

$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=1 | ./pipe-to-wc.ts
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1024 bytes (1.0 kB, 1.0 KiB) copied, 0.000116906 s, 8.8 MB/s
1024
```

But as soon as the input is big, only 65k bytes are going through!

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=100 | ./pipe-to-wc.ts
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
102400 bytes (102 kB, 100 KiB) copied, 0.0424347 s, 2.4 MB/s
65536
```

To fix this issue, let's replace the `write()` call with `writeAll()`:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env -S deno run --allow-read=/dev/stdin --allow-run=wc
const proc = await Deno.run({
  cmd: ['wc', '-c'],
  stdin: 'piped',
});

import { writeAll } from "https://deno.land/std@0.119.0/streams/conversion.ts";
await writeAll(proc.stdin, await Deno.readFile('/dev/stdin'));
proc.stdin.close();
await proc.status();
```

Now all the bytes are getting passed through on big inputs :D

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=1000 | ./pipe-to-wc.ts
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
1024000 bytes (1.0 MB, 1000 KiB) copied, 0.0854184 s, 12.0 MB/s
1024000
```

Note that this will still fail on huge inputs once they exceed the amount of memory available to your program. The `writeAll()` solution should be fine up to 100 megabytes or so. After that point you'd probably want to switch to a streaming solution.

Comment: I hadn't considered that the file might be a pretty big one 

Comment: @jsejcksn I'm definitely making a guess based on the name `dbDump.sql` :P
The real annoyance is that this failure state is silent because the write still "worked". This 65kb limit is only one source of partial writes. Basically any time you add a plain `write()` call, it's worth thinking "how annoying would it be if only some of the data got written?"

Comment: worked like magic, I think your theory is right that the write method has input size limitation as my dump is around 10mb,  just out of desperation and impatience I have written some code in golang and it had no issues writing the same dump to stdin. By the way some data was written few empty tables only though,  but not the remaining part which had puked a syntax issue.

Comment: It makes sense that some changes were already made in the database. The SQL program didn't know that the input got cut off, and when it reached the end, it tried making sense of what it still had. This can lead to various unexpected results! Also, if you want to do a streaming copy to support larger files, look at [`copy()`](https://doc.deno.land/https://deno.land/std@0.119.0/streams/conversion.ts/~/copy) which is also from the standard library that provides `writeAll()`.

Answer (score 1):

First, a couple of notes:

1. Deno currently doesn't offer a way to create a detached subprocess. (You didn't mention this, but it seems potentially relevant to your scenario given typical docker compose usage) See [denoland/deno#5501](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/5501).
2. Deno's subprocess API is currently being reworked. See [denoland/deno#11016](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/11016).

Second, here are links to the relevant docs:

- [`docker-compose exec`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/)
- [CLI APIs](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable) > [`Deno.run`](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/%7E/Deno.run)
- [Manual](https://deno.land/manual) > [Creating a subprocess (Deno `v1.17.0`)](https://deno.land/manual@v1.17.0/examples/subprocess)

Now, here's a commented breakdown of how to create a subprocess (according to the current API) using your scenario as an example:

`module.ts`:

```ts
const dbUser = 'actual_database_username';
const dbPass = 'actual_database_password'
const dbName = 'actual_database_name';

const dockerExecProcCmd = ['mysql', '-u', dbUser, '-p', dbPass, dbName];

const serviceName = 'actual_compose_service_name';

// Build the run command
const cmd = ['docker', 'compose', 'exec', '-T', serviceName, ...dockerExecProcCmd];

/**
 * Create the subprocess
 *
 * For now, leave `stderr` and `stdout` undefined so they'll print
 * to your console while you are debugging. Later, you can pipe (capture) them
 * and handle them in your program
 */
const p = Deno.run({
  cmd,
  stdin: 'piped',
  // stderr: 'piped',
  // stdout: 'piped',
});

/**
 * If you use a relative path, this will be relative to `Deno.cwd`
 * at the time the subprocess is created
 *
 * https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/~/Deno.cwd
 */
 const sqlFilePath = './dbDump.sql';

// Write contents of SQL script to stdin
await p.stdin.write(await Deno.readFile(sqlFilePath));

/**
 * Close stdin
 *
 * I don't know how `mysql` handles `stdin`, but if it needs the EOT sent by
 * closing and you don't need to write to `stdin` any more, then this is correct
 */
p.stdin.close();

// Wait for the process to finish (either OK or NOK)
const {code} = await p.status();
console.log({'docker-compose exit status code': code});

// Not strictly necessary, but better to be explicit
p.close();
```

Comment: Your code has exactly same problem as mine, it keeps throwing SQL syntax error that does not happen when you do same in cli.

Comment: @AndriusSolopovas I've updated my answer to include the `-T` argument to `docker compose exec` (which disables pseudo-TTY allocation). Does it work with that change?